# Compact Framework connecting to web service - How to use source port randomization

Tags: sockets, compact-framework, firewall

Compact Framework 3.5
Windows CE 6.0 R3
Atmel-based BSP

**Situation**: Multiple devices from a single gateway connecting to a web service that's behind a firewall.  All devices start the connection with the same IP and source port.

**Problem**:  Basically a new device is trying to connect to the web service, firewall thinks it's the existing connection, send a RST packet.  The device sequentially increments the source port, tries again.  If there are 100 devices, it's a 100 RSTs in  row, which takes a really long time.  (see http://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=8013&formaction=catalert)

The solution, according to the article, is to randomize the source port.  How is the source port determined and how can I set it?   I'm not even sure where it's being done (CE, CF, BSP).

---

*Edit:*
Found this [article about ServicePoint](http://www.netbrick.net/blog/PermaLink,guid,b9c255d9-74b4-45ab-8fd0-c9a04784655a.aspx). ServicePoint on the HttpWebRequest class looks promising, but the spec says:

> Windows Mobile for Pocket PC, Windows
>   Mobile for Smartphone, Windows CE
>   Platform Note: This property is null
>   until the request is sent because of
>   the additional network transmission
>   required.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem appears to be in winsock.dll.  What we ended up doing instantiating the Socket class and binding it to the Loopback endpoint a random number of times.